# Tomcat SSL port 8443 not responding

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

I have a server with a domain name and a lets encrypt certificate. I need to run my tomcat8 server on https so I generate a pfx file using my certificate with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem -password pass:*******
```

then in my /tomcat/conf/server.xml I added :

```
<Connector
         protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443"    
         keyAlias="tomcat"
         maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
         keystoreType="PKCS12"
         keystoreFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.internetsbh.com/bundle.pfx" 
         keystorePass="*******" 
         clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
/>
```

When I go to internetsbh.com:8443 it runs forever or it display the message: took to long to respond.

Is there something I am missing ? I also tried using a .jks instead of a pfx but I got the same result

thanks.

Comment: I think I have the same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: start by opening the catalina tomcat log

Answer (score 0):

another question that addresses something similar (also a nice checklist) : https://serverfault.com/questions/667487/tomcat-7-is-being-unresponsive-when-i-turn-on-ssl-no-ssl-handshake

i don't know about this mysterious entropy thing that is mentioned, but for sure, if you don't specify the right path for keystoreFile and truststoreFile, tomcat might show an error during the start of the process, but continue loading, resulting in unresponsiveness without further errors. there also might be a problem when access rights to the keystore file are not right

Of course, -Djavax.net.debug=all helps